# RabbitMQ - Can I Set Limits by Custom Attribute

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm evaluating using RabbitMQ as a message queue broker/framework to replace an internally built message queue (using C# if that matters).

I will have a service with N threads, each thread being a consumer for a specific queue.  There may be more than one thread that shares the same queue.  I believe I would use the prefetch property of 1 for each consumer so that a consumer thread receives 1 message at a time.

Lets use an example where I have 4 consumer threads and all look at a queue named "reports".  These reports can be run for different "customers".  I want to avoid allowing a customer to monopolize the queue so lets say I don't want any single customer to use more than 2 consumers at any given time (if there are other queued messages waiting).  If there are no other queued messages waiting for other customers then I'd like to allow all consumers to be eligible.

With my limited RabbitMQ understanding so far, I believe that I could either use a topic pattern to indicate the customer or I could use a custom header.

I'd like to know if there's a design pattern to support defining a limit per unique header/customer value.

I'm not asking for anyone to write the code for me, I just want to know if anyone can tell me "no that won't work" in advance before I waste a bunch of time getting ramped up.

If my question doesn't make sense please let me know and I'll update it with more information.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to look into [priority queues](https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html), have the priority to be set high, then decreasing it if the number of messages received for a given customer in a given period of time goes beyond a threshold (this would also mean that you'd need an intermediate step if the publishers are the customers)

Comment: Thanks @Olivier, I'll look into that some more.  Another option I was evaluating was the concept of the manual ACK and have the consumer check how many unacknowledged messages are outstanding for the queue grouped by customer and then "peek" if there's any messages on the queue (not distributed yet) for another customer.  If yes, then I thought I could have the consumer throw a negative Ack back and tell it to requeue.  I'm not sure if all that is possible yet.

Comment: If you "unack", the message will be requeued at the top of the queue, so that won't work. What you could possibly do is have the consumer republish the message through the exchange so that it ends up at the end of the queue. But as far as I know, there is no feature that would match the concept of peeking, you either consume (and possibly unack), or don't. If you wanted to go that road, you could possibly have the consumer(s) check somewhere else (DB, Redis, ...) for a count of processed messages for a given consumer and decide to republish the message without processing.

Comment: Thanks @Olivier.  We do this currently through our own database backed queue where our consumers essentially "pull" a message but it involves a lot of polling to the database and we don't love the scalability.  I'm also looking at Amazon MQ using ActiveMQ (we're a .net shop) so I'll try to assess if there's a different mechanism that might be possible with ActiveMQ.  I appreciate your input.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for the additional context. Out of curiosity, how many customers are we talking about?

Comment: We have 500+ customers but jobs aren't consistently received for all customers at one time.  I'm just trying to avoid a single customer flooding the queue with requests that other customers have to wait behind.  I realize thats not exactly a traditional FIFO queue so maybe I'm being naive thinking I can address that requirement using  a standard message queue framework.

Comment: I asked to see if another model with a queue per customer, then consumers going through each queue could be a workable model, but I think with 500+ customers, that's definitely an inadequate approach. Depending on how your customers "post" (call to an AP?), you could consider managing the throttling aspect earlier in your flow (with an API manager).